# How to reduce box size in jquery image cropper

Tags: javascript, jquery

I downloaded one jquery cropper plugin it is working fine ,but i want to change little bit,while cropping i want to change the size,that plugin like rectanglar box ,but i want squre,i dont know how to change  that plugin if anyone tell me means helpfull for me link https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper/

Answer (score 0):

On the lower right corner of this demo page there is a set of aspect ratios: 16:9, 4:3, 1:1, 2:3, Free. They have tooltips that suggest the option you should use. There's also some documentation about it [here](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper/blob/v2.0.1/README.md#options). In your case I believe it's:

```
$('#image').cropper({
    aspectRatio: 1 / 1,
    // ...
```

Which means a 1:1 aspect readio, i.e. a square.

Comment: I tried that one but after click the button get cropped image means ,that modal height should very high,it go down,we are scroll down then only we can see the full image,what will do now

Comment: Converting the aspect ratio would either cause a stretch or a second crop. If what you want is just a smaller image just use the parameters for width and height like it says right next to the "Get cropped canvas" button, on the "160x90" and "320x180" buttons: `.cropper("getCroppedCanvas", { width: 100, height: 100 })`